# Order by is not working correctly with Union ALL my sql

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, union

I have query where i want to list result as below:

[image: 1]
      [image: 2]

I have used below query to achiece it, but it is not working as expected, and sorting the result ASC or DESC.

```
SELECT * from (SELECT eventid, eventdate,eventdates FROM events WHERE events.onlineclosingdate>curdate() order by onlineclosingdate asc) a
UNION  ALL
SELECT * from (SELECT eventid, eventdate,eventdates FROM events WHERE events.onlineclosingdate<=curdate() order by onlineclosingdate desc) as c
```

Comment: write your complete query.

Comment: really what is missing in my Query Could you please tell me..?

Comment: order by eventid?

Comment: Why to order by eventID? when i don't need it.. i just need to order by date only

Comment: i write the answer below ignore ORDER BY if you don't needed it.

Comment: @RamgyBorja, please check your answer, i updated with output i am getting.. which is not matching what i requires.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153826/discussion-between-ram-singh-and-ramgy-borja).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you need to identify the 2 date period blocks and use a conditional order by for example
Given

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t (id int auto_increment primary key, dt date);

insert into t (dt) values
('2017-02-01'),('2017-10-01'),('2017-01-01'),
('2016-02-01'),('2016-10-01'),('2016-01-01');

select s.id,s.dt 
from
(
select 1 as srce,id,t.dt dt from t where dt > str_to_date('2016-12-31','%Y-%m-%d') 
union all
select 2,id,t.dt from t where dt <= str_to_date('2016-12-31','%Y-%m-%d') 
) s
order by srce asc,
            case when s.srce = 1 then s.dt end asc, 
            case when s.srce = 2 then s.dt end desc;

+----+------------+
| id | dt         |
+----+------------+
|  3 | 2017-01-01 |
|  1 | 2017-02-01 |
|  2 | 2017-10-01 |
|  5 | 2016-10-01 |
|  4 | 2016-02-01 |
|  6 | 2016-01-01 |
+----+------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score -1):

Union two queries and group in **One**

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT a.eventid as `eventid`, a.eventdate as `eventdate`, a.eventdates as `eventdates`  FROM events a WHERE a.onlineclosingdate>curdate() order by a.onlineclosingdate asc)
UNION  ALL
SELECT c.eventid as `eventid`, c.eventdate as `eventdate`, c.eventdates as `eventdates` FROM events c WHERE c.onlineclosingdate<=curdate() order by c.onlineclosingdate desc)
) as `all`
```

[image: Getting result like this]

Comment: so `eventdates` is not a `Date` type?

Comment: it is date type

Comment: please check the column name properly... .

Comment: yes `eventdates` is a Date type? how is there </br> there.

Comment: i implemented the order by "onlineclosingdate "  column bro